# Fresco: How to add RequestProperty to the ImageRequestBuilder?

Tags: android, properties, fresco

The image pipeline uses the `HttpURLConnection` networking library bundled with Android.

```
HttpURLConnection connection.setRequestProperty("Charset", "utf-8");
```

Fresco: How to add RequestProperty to the ImageRequestBuilder?

Comment: Fresco does not yet support this. Please file an issue on GitHub to request this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about request headers, Here is what I have done in my app

```
DiskCacheConfig mainDiskCacheConfig = DiskCacheConfig.newBuilder()
            .setBaseDirectoryPath(sContext.getCacheDir())
            .setBaseDirectoryName("cache")
            .setMaxCacheSize(1024 * 1024 * 1024) // max cache size
            .setMaxCacheSizeOnLowDiskSpace(50 * 1024 * 1024) // for low disk cache
            .setMaxCacheSizeOnVeryLowDiskSpace(10 * 1024 * 1024) // for
            .build();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
            com.squareup.okhttp.Request originalRequest = chain.request(); //Current Request
            com.squareup.okhttp.Request requestWithToken = null; //The request with the access token which we will use if we have one instead of the original
            requestWithToken = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader(Constant.AUTH_HEADER, BackgroundService.getAuthenticationHeader())
                    .addHeader(Constant.X_USER_ID, Wrapper.getInstance().getUserId())
                    .addHeader(Constant.X_DEVICE_KEY, DeviceUtils.getDeviceDetails(App.this).getAndroid_id())
                    .addHeader(Constant.X_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, Constant.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
                    .build();
            Response response = chain.proceed((requestWithToken != null ? requestWithToken : originalRequest)); //proceed with the request and get the response
            if (response != null && response.code() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                response.body().close();
            }
            return response;
        }
    });

    ImagePipelineConfig config = OkHttpImagePipelineConfigFactory.newBuilder(this, client)
            .setMainDiskCacheConfig(mainDiskCacheConfig)
            .build();
    Fresco.initialize(this, config);
```